# Missing required parameter: client_id SPOTIFY API ANGULAR PROJECT

Tags: angular, express

[image]

I am trying to deploy my project on heroku and I am getting this error `Missing required parameter: client_id`

But when I switched it back to localhost everything works perfect.

here is my `server.js` code:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const querystring = require('querystring');
const request = require('request');

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    dotenv.config()
}

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
// Setting
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/spotify/dist/spotify"));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(
    express.urlencoded({
        extended: true,
    })
);

    app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
            querystring.stringify({
                response_type: 'code',
                client_id: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
                scope: 'user-read-recently-played user-read-private user-read-email user-top-read playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private playlist-read-private playlist-read-collaborative user-follow-read',
                redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI
            }));
    });

    app.get('/callback', (req, res) => {
        const code = req.query.code || null;

        const authOptions = {
            url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            form: {
                code: code,
                redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code'
            },
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer.from(
                    process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID + ':' + process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET
                ).toString('base64'))
            },
            json: true
        };

        request.post(authOptions, (error, response, body) => {
            const access_token = body.access_token;
            const uri = process.env.FRONTEND_URI;
            res.redirect(uri + '?access_token=' + access_token);
        });
    });

    require("./server/config/routes.js")(app);

    // Localhost
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
```

ERROR

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
>   /favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
>   status of 404 ()

Comment: It sounds like it isnt being set. You can set a variable with the cli:  ```heroku config:set SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID =YOUR_KEY_HERE```

Comment: @MarcusCantu Is it a command line in terminal or how can i set it in heroku

Comment: You should be able to just use it in the terminal. [Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) is a link on how to do it in the heroku dashboard